# Variable number of rows as table headers with data beneath

Tags: sql-server-2008-r2

I have inherited a database which I am trying to extract some information from.  I can do much of what I want with SQL without any issues, but I don't really know where to start with this query.

There are four tables relevant to the query as follows:

```
Clients

ID  |  Client Name | Client Reference
-------------------------------------
1   | Acme Inc     | ACM
2   | Sprocket Inc | SPR

Customers_Table

ID  | Client | Customer Name
----------------------------
1   | 1      | Fred
2   | 1      | Sarah
3   | 2      | Mary
4   | 2      | Dave

Custom_Questions

ID  | Client | Question
---------------------------------------------------
1   | 1      | What is the name of your dog?
2   | 1      | How old is your dog?
3   | 2      | What is your cat's name?
4   | 2      | When was the cat's last vet visit?

Answers

ID | Customer | Question | Answer
---------------------------------
1  | 1        | 1        | Rover
2  | 1        | 2        | 10
3  | 2        | 1        | Bob
4  | 2        | 2        | 1
5  | 3        | 3        | Trixie
6  | 3        | 4        | Never
7  | 4        | 3        | Furball
8  | 4        | 4        | Last year
```

The system has clients, who can have multiple customers.  The clients can ask the customers a variable number of custom questions.  The custom questions are in one table, the answers in another.

Basically, I need to create a report for each of the clients, listing the customer, questions and answers like this:

```
Client 1 Report:

Customer Name | What is the name of your dog? | How old is your dog?
====================================================================
Fred          | Rover                         | 10
Sarah         | Bob                           | 1
```

It seems to be a bit like an excel pivot table, but I can't find anything appropriate on Google that looks like this.  Can anyone give me some pointers on what I should be searching for or what commands I should be looking at?

Thanks

Comment: Are you using SSRS?

Comment: No; the machine is actually an AWS RDS instance.  Not sure if I can use it on that?  I've tended to use pure SQL for most things.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
IF OBJECT_ID ('tempdb..#Clients') is not null drop table #Clients
IF OBJECT_ID ('tempdb..#Answers') is not null drop table #Answers
IF OBJECT_ID ('tempdb..#CustomQuestions') is not null drop table #CustomQuestions
IF OBJECT_ID ('tempdb..#CustomersTable') is not null drop table #CustomersTable
IF OBJECT_ID ('tempdb..#Holding') is not null drop table #Holding


DECLARE @ID int --this is the client ID of interest
SET @ID = 1

--create some work tables for testing

create table #Clients(
ID int,
ClientName varchar(128),
ClientReference varchar(3))

insert into #Clients (ID, ClientName, ClientReference) values
(1,'Acme Inc','ACM'),
(2,'Sproket Inc', 'SPR')


create table #CustomersTable(
ID int,
Client int,
CustomerName varchar(128))

insert into #CustomersTable(ID, Client,CustomerName) values
(1,1,'Fred'),
(2,1,'Sarah'),
(3,2,'Mary'),
(4,2,'Dave')


create table #CustomQuestions(
ID int,
Client int,
Question varchar(max))

insert into #CustomQuestions (ID, Client, Question) values
(1,1,'What is the name of your dog'),
(2,1,'How old is your dog'),
(3,2,'What is your cats name'),
(4,2,'When was the cats last visit')

create table #Answers(
ID int,
Customer int,
Question int,
Answer varchar(max))

insert into #Answers(ID, Customer,Question, Answer) values
(1,1,1,'Rover'),
(2,1,2,'10'),
(3,2,1,'Bob'),
(4,2,2,'1'),
(5,3,3,'Trixie'),
(6,3,4,'Never'),
(7,4,3,'Furball'),
(8,4,4,'Last year')


--get your data for the client you need

select
    c.ClientName,
    ct.CustomerName,
    q.Question,
    a.Answer
into #Holding
from
    #Clients c
    inner join #CustomersTable ct on
    ct.Client = c.ID
    inner join #Answers a on
    a.Customer = ct.ID
    inner join #CustomQuestions q on
    q.id = a.Question
where
    c.ID = @ID


--Now piviot, with a dynamic amount of questions

DECLARE @DynamicPivotQuery AS NVARCHAR(MAX)
DECLARE @ColumnName AS NVARCHAR(MAX)


SELECT @ColumnName= ISNULL(@ColumnName + ',','') 
       + QUOTENAME(Question)
FROM (SELECT DISTINCT Question FROM #Holding) AS Question

--Prepare the PIVOT query using the dynamic 
SET @DynamicPivotQuery = 
  N'SELECT CustomerName, ' + @ColumnName + '
    FROM #Holding
    PIVOT(Max(Answer) 
          FOR Question IN (' + @ColumnName + ')) AS PVTTable'

EXEC sp_executesql @DynamicPivotQuery
```

Comment: That is absolutely fantastic - thank you.  I'll now go and have a good look at the pivot command.